# cannot coerce class ‘"json"’ to a data.frame

Tags: r

I'm extracting values out of json and then I'm trying to create a frame for each value, this all works apart from when I convert a frame to a json string and try to put in a new frame.

I've printed the type and it appears as character so I'm unsure why I get the error about coercing json into a frame if the type is character.

Could you show me how to create the frame with the code below?

```
labels <- toJSON(data.frame(type=type_vector, label=label_vector))

#[{"type":"image","label":"1"},{"type":"image","label":"2"},{"type":"image","label":"3"}] 

print(typeof(labels))

#"character"

data_frame <- data.frame(id="123", labels=labels)

# Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"json"’ to a data.frame
```

Comment: Can't reproduce this. Maybe sharing your actual `labels` via `dput` would help?

Comment: @RitchieSacramento thanks as.character did it